# Shell alias not recognized in Fortran system call

Tags: bash, fortran, system, alias

I have created a command using "alias" in `.bashrc` as following

```
alias lsw="ls |wc -l"
```

when I write in Fortran

```
call system ("lsw")
```

I am getting following error

```
sh: 1: lsw: not found
```

Could you please advise me how I can solve this?

Comment: Anyway, bash aliases cannot be called from outside of bash. The user needs to wrap the command in bash program and call the bash program explicitly.

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference if he used the standard `EXECUTE_COMMAND_LINE`  @PierredeBuyl you could work that up as an answer.

Comment: I advise against this, even if you could get it to work.  Aliases can be a support nightmare.  Imagine trying to debug your FORTRAN program when trying to run it under a user id when the alias is not present.  Aliases are really only productivity aids to reduce typing, there is little (or no) advantage in using them from a compiled program.

Comment: Indeed I expect that is why the bash developers made it deliberately difficult to use aliases in a non-interactive shell.